# Эффект статического текста при скролле

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Прошу прощения за название. Я даже не представляю как правильно задать вопрос. При скролле текст нового блока накладывается на предыдущий([см. jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLgu72uc)). Я понимаю почему это происходит, но как этого избежать? С или без js не важно. Даже с js у меня нет ни малейшей идеи как это реализовать.
Проскролльте пример до конца, что бы понять в чем проблема.

```css
body {
    background: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background: no-repeat fixed center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg table {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table td {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col1 {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/JU71kee.jpg")
}
.col2 {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/mRI807h.jpg")
}
.col3 {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/E11e6Mk.jpg")
}
.col4 {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/KcEHPYF.jpg")
}
```

```html
<div class="bg col1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Page 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="bg col2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Page 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="bg col3">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Page 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="bg col4">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Page 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: В этом то и дело. Текст не должен двигаться. Это не то что нужно.
"Page #" должно оставаться в статическом положении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получился достаточно экспериментальный вариант с использованием события `scroll`. Задача и правда не тривиальная, как сделать чистым CSS вообще пока не приходит в голову.

Сразу ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bxrv1wg/1/), а тут расскажу основные моменты.

На странице есть N блоков, высота которых = высоте окна, в каждом из этих блоков посередине по высоте располагается текст (`.text`). При загрузке страницы вытягивается положение по высоте первого блока (переменная `middle`), и предполагается что остальные блоки с текстом также смещены на такую же высоту относительно родителей. Обработчик запускается при каждом событии `scroll` и при первой загрузке страницы. При скролле страница вместе с родителями перемещается вверх на значение `window.scrollY`, и чтобы создать иллюзию того, что текст зафиксирован, каждый блок с текстом тоже двигаем на `window.scrollY`, но текст будет двигаться не относительно страницы, а относительно родителя. Благодаря `overflow:hidden` текст в конце-концов будет скрыт в рамках родителя и позволит создать эффект перехода одного текста в другой. Но из-за того, что `window.scrollY` работает на всю страницу, а блоки с текстами только относительно родителей, нужно как-то их сопоставить друг с другом. Для этого с помощью переменной `multiplier` "более нижние" блоки с текстом заранее смещаются выше.

```
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
var middle = blocks[0].offsetTop;

function update() {

  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {

    var multiplier = 1 - i * 2;

    var top = multiplier * middle + window.scrollY;

    blocks[i].style.top = top + 'px';
  }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', update);

update();
```

Решение немного хрупкое, но, надеюсь, будет хотя бы толчком для начала.

Comment: Оно работает! Конечно, придется допилить под разный размер текста, но это уже на много лучше чем ничего) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Думается, что ошибка в bg, смотрите свойство display, для div и table.

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, более подробные и полные ответы. В таком случае это поможет большему количеству участников.

Comment: Хм. Посмотрите внимательно на структуру. Данные свойства ничего не изменят.